# Cannot install MySQL server 5.7 and 5.6

Tags: mysql, windows, installation

I am using Windows 10, and installed all visual studio 2013 X86 and X64 versions. I tried different verions (5.7 and 5.6) of MySQL. All of them fails. The log message is shown below. I cannot figure out what the problem is..

```
1: File: func.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 8665
1: File: func.MYD,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 0
1: File: func.MYI,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 1024
1: File: general_log.CSM,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 35
1: File: general_log.CSV,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 0
1: File: general_log.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 8776
1: File: help_category.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 8700
1: File: help_category.MYD,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 1120
1: File: help_category.MYI,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 3072
1: File: help_keyword.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 8612
1: File: help_keyword.MYD,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 121943
1: File: help_keyword.MYI,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 22528
1: File: help_relation.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 8630
1: File: help_relation.MYD,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 11457
1: File: help_relation.MYI,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 22528
1: File: help_topic.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 8770
1: File: help_topic.MYD,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 575100
1: File: help_topic.MYI,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 22528
1: File: host_cache.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\performance_schema\,  Size: 10483
1: File: hosts.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\performance_schema\,  Size: 8676
1: File: ib_logfile0,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\,  Size: 50331648
1: File: ib_logfile1,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\,  Size: 50331648
1: File: ibdata1,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\,  Size: 12582912
1: File: innodb_index_stats.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 12982
1: File: innodb_index_stats.ibd,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 98304
1: File: innodb_table_stats.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 8830
1: File: innodb_table_stats.ibd,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 98304
1: File: mutex_instances.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\performance_schema\,  Size: 8684
1: File: ndb_binlog_index.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 8898
1: File: ndb_binlog_index.MYD,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 0
1: File: ndb_binlog_index.MYI,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 1024
1: File: objects_summary_global_by_type.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\performance_schema\,  Size: 8908
1: File: performance_timers.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\performance_schema\,  Size: 8776
1: File: plugin.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 8586
1: File: plugin.MYD,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 0
1: File: plugin.MYI,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 1024
1: File: proc.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 9996
1: File: proc.MYD,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 0
1: File: proc.MYI,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 2048
1: File: procs_priv.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 8875
1: File: procs_priv.MYD,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 0
1: File: procs_priv.MYI,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 4096
1: File: proxies_priv.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 8800
1: File: proxies_priv.MYD,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 693
1: File: proxies_priv.MYI,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 5120
1: File: rwlock_instances.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\performance_schema\,  Size: 8758
1: File: servers.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 8838
1: File: servers.MYD,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 0
1: File: servers.MYI,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 1024
1: File: session_account_connect_attrs.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\performance_schema\,  Size: 8716
1: File: session_connect_attrs.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\performance_schema\,  Size: 8716
1: File: setup_actors.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\performance_schema\,  Size: 8620
1: File: setup_consumers.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\performance_schema\,  Size: 8605
1: File: setup_instruments.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\performance_schema\,  Size: 8637
1: File: setup_objects.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\performance_schema\,  Size: 8751
1: File: setup_timers.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\performance_schema\,  Size: 8650
1: File: slave_master_info.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 10719
1: File: slave_master_info.ibd,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 98304
1: File: slave_relay_log_info.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 9334
1: File: slave_relay_log_info.ibd,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 98304
1: File: slave_worker_info.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 9230
1: File: slave_worker_info.ibd,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 98304
1: File: slow_log.CSM,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 35
1: File: slow_log.CSV,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 0
1: File: slow_log.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 9016
1: File: socket_instances.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\performance_schema\,  Size: 8818
1: File: socket_summary_by_event_name.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\performance_schema\,  Size: 9740
1: File: socket_summary_by_instance.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\performance_schema\,  Size: 9804
1: File: table_io_waits_summary_by_index_usage.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\performance_schema\,  Size: 10578
1: File: table_io_waits_summary_by_table.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\performance_schema\,  Size: 10488
1: File: table_lock_waits_summary_by_table.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\performance_schema\,  Size: 13518
1: File: tables_priv.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 8955
1: File: tables_priv.MYD,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 0
1: File: tables_priv.MYI,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 4096
1: File: threads.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\performance_schema\,  Size: 9201
1: File: time_zone.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 8636
1: File: time_zone.MYD,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 0
1: File: time_zone.MYI,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 1024
1: File: time_zone_leap_second.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 8624
1: File: time_zone_leap_second.MYD,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 0
1: File: time_zone_leap_second.MYI,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 1024
1: File: time_zone_name.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 8606
1: File: time_zone_name.MYD,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 0
1: File: time_zone_name.MYI,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 1024
1: File: time_zone_transition.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 8686
1: File: time_zone_transition.MYD,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 0
1: File: time_zone_transition.MYI,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 1024
1: File: time_zone_transition_type.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 8748
1: File: time_zone_transition_type.MYD,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 0
1: File: time_zone_transition_type.MYI,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 1024
1: File: user.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 10684
1: File: user.MYD,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 296
1: File: user.MYI,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mysql\,  Size: 2048
1: File: users.frm,  Directory: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\performance_schema\,  Size: 8676
1: Action 2:24:17: CreateShortcuts. Creating shortcuts
1: Shortcut: icon.ico
1: Shortcut: Icon.MysqlCmdShell
1: Shortcut: ewo_tetn|MySQL 5.6 Command Line Client
1: Shortcut: 3oirwn95|MySQL 5.6 Command Line Client - Unicode
1: Action 2:24:17: WriteRegistryValues. Writing system registry values
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.6, Name: Location, Value: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.6, Name: Version, Value: 5.6.38
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.6, Name: DataLocation, Value: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.6, Name: , Value: 
1: Key: \Console\MySQL 5.6 Command Line Client - Unicode, Name: FaceName, Value: Lucida Console
1: Key: \Console\MySQL 5.6 Command Line Client - Unicode, Name: FontWeight, Value: #400
1: Key: \Console\MySQL 5.6 Command Line Client - Unicode, Name: , Value: 
1: Key: \Software\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.6, Name: installed, Value: #1
1: Action 2:24:17: ExecSecureObjects. 
1: Action 2:24:17: Rollback. Rolling back action:
1: ExecSecureObjects
1: Writing system registry values
1: Creating shortcuts
1: Copying new files
1: Creating folders
1: Updating component registration
1: 1: MySQL Server 5.6 2: {23E23AF3-E04A-4A3E-BDFA-92A9F4DD8EF8} 3: 3 
1: The action 'Install' for product 'MySQL Server 5.6.38' failed.
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem. No Visual studio installed, since I am not trying to do anything except use the server. Clean install of Windows 10 Pro